# copy and pasting multiple rows using some condition

Tags: excel, row, vba

I have to write a macro to *conditionally* copy certain rows. If user enters some number in any empty cell, say A55, this number will be matched to column A (or A1) if the number is found in A1, then the whole row should be selected. And if the number is found in multiple places in column A then it should copy all the rows and paste them in new worksheet say sheet2.

Here is my code which only accesses all the rows in which A55 number is found and I'm not sure how to copy selected rows:

```
copyandpaste() 
    Dim x As String 
    Dim matched As Integer 
    Range("A1").Select 
    x = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A55") 
    matched = 0 
         Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) 
        If ActiveCell.Value = x Then 
            matched = matched + 1 
        End If 
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 
    Loop 
    MsgBox "Total number of matches are : " & matched 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, you might need to change **xlWhole** to **xlPart** in the FIND command.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyAndPaste()
Dim x As String, CpyRng As Range
Dim mFIND As Range, mFIRST As Range

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        x = .Range("A55")
        On Error Resume Next
        Set mFIND = .Range("A1:A54").Find(x, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not mFIND Is Nothing Then
            Set CpyRng = mFIND
            Set mFIRST = mFIND

            Do
                Set CpyRng = Union(CpyRng, mFIND)
                Set mFIND = .Range("A1:A54").FindNext(mFIND)
            Loop Until mFIND.Address = mFIRST.Address

            CpyRng.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

If you move the "x" cell out of column A, or used a popup box, then you could just search the entire column A:A, instead of the short range I designated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extreamlly simplistic way to achieve what you want to do. It simply presents the user with a box to enter a value and copies all rows in which that value is in column A and puts them on a new sheet.

```
Sub CustomCopy()

Dim strsearch As String
Dim lastline As Long, toCopy As Long
Dim searchColumn As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim c As range

strsearch = CStr(InputBox("Enter the value to search for"))

lastline = range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
j = 1

For i = 1 To lastline
    If range("A" & i).Value = strsearch Then
       Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next

MsgBox j - 1 & " row(s) copied to Sheet2."

End Sub
```